# How to display combo drop down list above combobox in C# windows?

Tags: c#, combobox

By default combo box drop down list is displayed below(bottom) of combo box,I want to display it above combo box(top).ref image uploaded[image]

Update -
I try to create own comboBox, as shown here:
[enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996411)

is any other solution using default windows combobox control

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please show us what you have tried, what does not work.

Comment: I found this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395747/combobox-dropdown-position  Maybe it can help you. It wont look as nice as the default dropdown but its something

Comment: is any other solution using default windows combobox control

Comment: A combobox has a drop**down** list. While I understand your intention, I cannot imagine that I would be happy with a drop**up** list in a standard combobox control.