# changing combo box drop down position in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

How can I change the dropdown position (width and height) of a combobox. I docked the combobox to right of the form for the requirement,As the dropdown width is more than the combobox width, it goes out of the form.

How can I fix this !!!

Comment: There should be a setting for the drop down width in the properties, if not, you can handle the DropDownOpen event and see dropdown width to combo box width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by this post
[ComboBox Dropdown Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395747/combobox-dropdown-position)

This works fine when I use below codes

```
MyComboBox cmb = new MyComboBox();
cmb.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
cmb.Items.Add("Hello world");
cmb.Items.Add("How are you man");
cmb.SelectedIndex = 0;
this.Controls.Add(cmb);
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code where you created your combobox add this code.

```
this.ComboBox1.DropDownWidth = 200; //just give the width you want
```

Comment: the I already set dropdownwidth, but as it is more than the combobox width, it is going out of form....Please check my exact question !!!

Comment: check this link (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownwidth(v=vs.110).aspx)