# Windows Forms ComboBox DropDown Position

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

[image]

Usually dropdown item start position aligned with `ComboBox` start position like the image above.
But i need to develop `ComboBox` Control which has the lengthy dropdown item gets aligned in middle.I mean Dropdown item left position should still more left positioned than `ComboBox` like the image below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You may find this post useful: [ComboBox Dropdown Position](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2396052/3110834)

Comment: Also this article: [Building a Better ComboBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996411.aspx)

Comment: thanks @RezaAghaei ! the 2nd seems helpful. Let me try build with its help.

Comment: I posted an extended ComboBox which have 2 new useful features to let you set the position and size of drop-down. `DropDownAlignment` and `AutoWidthDropDown`. The first lets you set the alignment of dropdown be set to left, middle and right. The second lets you to set the width of dropdown set to the longest item automatically.

Comment: Its goal is different than the linked posts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is an extended [`ComboBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) which have 2 new useful features to let you set the position and size of drop-down:

- `DropDownAlignment`: You can set it to `Left`, then the drop-down will appear in it's normal position and it's left is aligned with left of control. If you set it to `Middle`, the middle of drop-down will be aligned with control and if you set it to `Right`, the right of drop-down will be aligned with right of control.
- `AutoWidthDropDown`: If you set it to `true` to, then `DropdownWidth` will be set to the width of the longest item. If you set it to `false` it uses `Width` as `DropDownWidth`.

Here is appearance of drop-down after setting `AutoWidthDropDown` to `true` and `DropDownAlignment` to `Left`, `Middle` and `Right`:

[image: Left]

[image: Middle]

[image: Right]

#### Implementation - ComboBox with DropDown Position and AutoWith DropDown

You can handle [`WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-ctlcolorlistbox?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) message, the `lparam` is the handle of drop-down and then you can set position of drop-down using [`SetWindowPos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

Also you can calculate width of longest item and set as `DropDownWidth` if `AutoWidthDropDown` is true.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;
```

```
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    private const UInt32 WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX = 0x0134;
    private const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x1;
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter,
        int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
    public enum DropDownAlignments { Left = 0, Middle, Right }
    public bool AutoWidthDropDown { get; set; }
    public DropDownAlignments DropDownAlignment { get; set; }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX)  {
            var bottomLeft = this.PointToScreen(new Point(0, Height));
            var x = bottomLeft.X;
            if (DropDownAlignment == MyComboBox.DropDownAlignments.Middle)
                x -= (DropDownWidth - Width) / 2;
            else if (DropDownAlignment == DropDownAlignments.Right)
                x -= (DropDownWidth - Width);
            var y = bottomLeft.Y;
            SetWindowPos(m.LParam, IntPtr.Zero, x, y, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
    protected override void OnDropDown(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (AutoWidthDropDown)
            DropDownWidth = Items.Cast<Object>().Select(x => GetItemText(x))
                  .Max(x => TextRenderer.MeasureText(x, Font,
                       Size.Empty, TextFormatFlags.Default).Width);
        else
            DropDownWidth = this.Width;
        base.OnDropDown(e);
    }
}
```