# How to align Combobox values on center, without spaces?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have 3 values in my combobox (1,2,3), and I want those values to be in the center, but the combobox does not have any text align properties. Spacing does not help (...1,...2,...3).

UI is ok like that, but without square brackets:

[image]

In CSV file it should be like that, without WiFi description, just the value.

[image]

My code for writing into CSV file.

```
new Settings_Admin
{
    cur_mul = cur_mul.Text,
    CONN_MODE = conn_mode.SelectedItem.ToString(),
    MSG_TIME = msg_time.Text,
    ADC_TIME = adc_time.Text,
    CUR_RANGE = cur_range.Text,
    PT_offset = pt_offset.Text,
}
```

Someone have a alternative answer for me?

```
conn_mode.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("1", "WiFi"));
conn_mode.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("2", "GSM"));
conn_mode.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("3", "Offline"));
```

Comment: could you add a screenshot of the actual outcome and may be even the desired outcome on the display?

Comment: You could also try to use the string [composite formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/txafckwd(v=vs.90)). More explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579506/how-to-do-alignment-within-string-format-in-c

Comment: no, he suggests the following that is not suitable for me...
"As a possible workaround, you could perhaps do something outlandish like padding the item strings with spaces so they look centered. You'll need TextRenderer.MeasureText() to figure out how many spaces to add for each item."

Comment: @George: look at the most upvoted answer not the accepted one.

Comment: If you don't want the WiFi description, just the value, why do you use `KeyValuePair<string, string>("1", "WiFi")` and not just `"1"`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 because it's nice for the end user to see, what each value represents.

Comment: Then I don't understand why you write "I want it to be like that, without WiFi description, just the value."

Comment: For both the editable area and the dropdown's text you can [align to center](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58955315/3110834).

Comment: Even for the dropdown (menu), you can [specify the position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39041737/3110834).