# C# winforms, How can I make a Combobox open upwards / Is there one that does?

Tags: c#, winforms

In C#, a winforms application,

How can I make a Combobox that opens upwards / Is there one that opens upwards?

I see some questions like this but they refer to a WPF application rather than  a winforms one. I'm asking about a winforms application.

Comment: Not possible unless you write a control of your own.

Comment: Drag the form to the bottom of your screen, then open the combo box. Like magic, it opens upwards!

Comment: @KobyDouek perhaps one has been written that I can use?

Comment: It's possible to achieve this effect by subclassing the control and manipulating its behavior using Windows API functions. (Start with code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2395747/).) But the problem with this is that the OS uses slide effects, and there's no way to change the direction of these, so it'll appear to slide down and then the drop down list will appear above it. Ugly. Perhaps you can explain why you need to worry about this, instead of letting the window manager handle it automatically? Your design should not rely on the combo box dropping in any particular direction.

Comment: @CodyGray   Your earlier comment said  "Drag the form to the bottom of your screen, then open the combo box. Like magic, it opens upwards! " <-- mine doesn't http://i.imgur.com/xipBJF1.png

Comment: Well, no, because there's plenty of room to display it on top of your oversized taskbar.

Comment: @CodyGray a problem is that sometimes when I hover over a taskbar icon then the icon expands showing the windows and covers the combobox. So if I click an option then straight after I clicked it it covers what option was clicked. I like to  be able to see, in the comobox, the option I  clicked immediately after I clicked it.  In this case cmd window icon in taskbar is behind one the option in the combobox  that I clicked. http://i.imgur.com/QL7vwz3.png

Comment: It is a simple Z order issue. The thing the user is currently interacting with is at the top of the Z order. In the beginning, that was the combobox, so it was on top, above the task bar. Then, you hovered over one of the taskbar icons, and it showed its own pop-up which was placed at the top of the Z order. What you're quibbling about is how the operating system's window manager was designed. If you don't like it, file a bug with Microsoft. All other applications will behave exactly the same way. There is no real way for your app to work around it. The pop-up can still cover a dropped up cbx.

Comment: @CodyGray so i'm saying if the combobox menu came upwards then it won't be over the taskbar and I wouldn't have that problem. Perhaps there is a control that has been written that opens upwards.

Comment: That assertion is incorrect, though. It is still possible that a pop-up from the task bar would cover a combobox that had been "dropped up". And if you *always* dropped the combobox up, it would go off the top of the screen, so you'd need special handling for that. No, there's no built-in control that has been written for this. I don't know if there's a 3rd-party control that has, but (1) Stack Overflow is not a recommendation engine, so that question would be off-topic, and (2) I can guarantee that it is buggy and sucks so bad you won't want to use it in a professional application.

Comment: Re my last comment, what I could do is reposition the cursor to be eg on the combobox, after the value has changed. So the cursor isn't on the taskbar.immediately after the user chooses an option

Comment: @CodyGray   Isn't it the case that the only way a popup from the taskbar could cover a combobox that has been opened upwards, would be if while it is opened upwards,  the user then moved the mouse over a taskbar icon. That is quite different to the user clicking a value in the combobox and having a taskbar icon window list come immediately. Also i'm not going to be operating a combobox that is positioned such that it's covered by the taskbar as then I can't see the combobox anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145831/discussion-between-barlop-and-cody-gray).

Comment: Sorry, I don't do chat, and I don't really know that there is any advantage in extending this discussion. You are certainly free to hack around with various things if you want, but I can tell you that they won't work well and you'll be fighting interface bugs forever. Best to just use the standard controls the way that the window manager intended for them to be used. Repositioning the cursor is a *terrible* idea; it is very disorienting to the user and again, just another source of bugs.

Comment: @CodyGray I didn't choose the words "Let us continue this discussion in chat". I chose to move the discussion there 'cos it's neater there in terms of the system. I just added some points re the subject. I wasn't really extending the discussion / addressing you or anybody else in the last remark, though the chat feature merged it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

This is not easy when working with WinForms, but I could give you my idea.

You should know that even when the combobox visible property is set to false, its' dropdown menu can still be displayed programmatically.
So the idea is that creating a user control that contains 2 comboboxs:

[Example of my user control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZuVN.png)

The upper combobox is invisible. When user clicks the main, below one, the upper one will be relocated and drop down.

```
        private void cbb_main_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cbb_2.Location = new Point(cbb_main.Location.X, cbb_main.Location.Y - cbb_2.Size.Height - (cbb_2.ItemHeight *cbb_2.Items.Count));
        cbb_main.DroppedDown = false;
        cbb_2.DroppedDown = true;
    }
```

Finally, add your custom control to the form and give it a try!
[Result image here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD5Nv.png)

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If there is enough in your combobox, and your form is low enough, that the contents of the combobox hits as far as very near the bottom of the screen, then it will open upwards.

Downwards

[image]

---

Now i'll drag the form down a little bit. (Or I could add some elements to the combobox) And you see it opens upwards.

Upwards

[image]

---

Sure it would be better if it popped upwards when it covered a bit of taskbar(or if the combobox took priority in z-order, which it doesn't seem to). An annoying thing is if it's in a limbo where it is covering the taskbar 'cos the contents aren't falling low enough for it to pop upwards. Then when you select something low in the combobox you also hover over something in the taskbar, then windows 7 can open eg an explorer window as you hover over a group of them in the taskbar. (And btw that issue exists whatever size your taskbar is). But in that scenario, as this answer says, you could drag the form a bit lower to get around that.